# Scala - extensions with Traits

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to understand how Odresky has apply (in an example) the extensions of applications in functionality through using Traits and here is the code:

```
trait Base {
  type exp <: Exp

  trait Exp {
    def eval: Int
  }

  class Num(v: Int) extends Exp {
    val value = v
    def eval = value
  }
}

trait BasePlus extends Base {
  class Plus(l: exp, r: exp) extends Exp {
    val left = l
    val right = r
    def eval = left.eval + right.eval
  }
}

trait BaseNeg extends Base {
  class Neg(t: exp) extends Exp {
    val term = t
    def eval = -term.eval
  }  
}

trait Show extends Base {
  type exp <: Exp

  trait Exp extends super.Exp {
    def show: String
  }

  class Num(v: Int) extends super.Num(v) with Exp {
    def show = value.toString()
  }
}

trait BasePlusNeg extends BasePlus with BaseNeg

trait ShowPlusNeg extends BasePlusNeg with Show {
  class Plus(l:exp, r: exp) extends super.Plus(l, r) with Exp {
    def show = left.show + "+" + right.show
  }
  class Neg(t: exp) extends super.Neg(t) with Exp {
    def show = "-(" + term.show + ")"
  }
}


trait DblePlusNeg extends BasePlusNeg {
  type exp <: Exp

  trait Exp extends super.Exp {
    def dble: exp
  }

  def Num(v: Int): exp
  def Plus(l: exp, r: exp): exp
  def Neg(t:exp): exp

  class Num(v: Int) extends super.Num(v) with Exp {
    def dble = Num(v * 2)
  }
  class Plus(l: exp, r:exp) extends super.Plus(l, r) with Exp {
    def dble = Plus(left.dble, right.dble)
  }
  class Neg(t: exp) extends super.Neg(t) with Exp {
    def dble = Neg(t.dble)
  }
}

trait ShowDblePlusNeg extends ShowPlusNeg with DblePlusNeg {
  type exp <: Exp
  trait Exp extends super[ShowPlusNeg].Exp with super[DblePlusNeg].Exp
  class Num(v: Int) extends super[ShowPlusNeg].Num(v) with super[DblePlusNeg].Num(v) with Exp //error
  class Plus(l: exp, r: exp) extends super[ShowPlusNeg].Plus(l, r) with super[DblePlusNeg].Plus(l, r) with Exp //error
  class Neg(t: exp) extends super[ShowPlusNeg].Neg(t) with super[DblePlus.Neg].Neg(t) with Exp //error
}
```

The last three mixings will not compile because

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - traits or objects may not have parameters
    - class Num needs to be a trait to be mixed in
```

- I am guessing that it is implemented with the previous versions of Scala 1.4 but anyway a class never has been able to offer mixing, nor in previous versions. How I can mix without the need to change the classes in Traits?

Comment: yes but not with the keyword `with` and frankly they are concrete classes = everything are defined and implemented on them.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying in your edit. Please express the question in clearer (and perhaps more grammatical) sentences.

Comment: @Imm, you can ignore my 'Edit', ... it's about How to make the current mixing to be functional - in this current code. That's all.

Comment: @johny, I know that and the error message is saying the same thing but my cocern is that I received this example exactly from a paper of Odersky `Independently extensible solutions to the expression problem` and I don't get how they have described that it is functional refering the inner classes in a trait in that way!!!!